# Should HOA notice me the price of the quote and pay for the fan removal?

Tags: payment, hoa

My HOA is doing this project on my balcony, where I have a fan through the wall. They need me to remove and reinstall it on my cost. I thought it is a HOA project, they may pay for it. Then they said they would consider reimbursing me. So they went ahead to get quote of $800-900, and started the work. Now they charged me as maintenance. Please let me know what my options are? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to provide more details for a rather specific response. (1) The exact terms of what the HOA told you about reimbursement are relevant. (2) Did the HOA give you the assurance *in writing*? (3) Why did the HOA require you to remove and reinstall the fan? (4) What do the bylaws or related agreements indicate in this type of issues?

Comment: HOA is renovating the balcony. They said in email" HOA will certainly consider to reimburse for it". By CA HOA CCR, the owner may be responsible. My issue is that HOA first gave me the impression to pay for it, then charged on me without noticing me the quote.

Comment: What do you mean by "CA HOA CCR"? I presume CA stands for California. I don't see CCR in [list of California codes](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/home.xhtml). Could you specify the statute(s) regarding "*the owner may be responsible*"?

Comment: CC&R of HOA. Fan belongs owner, even though it is a HOA project

Answer (score 1):

Your options seem fairly obvious:

1. Pay the maintenance and be done with it.
2. Raise the issue with the HOA and request a review of the charge.
3. File a lawsuit against the HOA if you believe they have violated the terms of the agreement and possibly what they represented to you.  Hopefully that was done in writing.
4. Simply ignore the charge and let things play out.

There are pros and cons to each of these.  I believe the best approach would be to start with #2 and see how that goes.

Comment: I did the appeal. They insisted on me paying it. If I ignore the charge, eventually I may have to pay the extra interest. They may say "we decide not to pay for it" after "considering the imbursement". The thing was that, if they considered to pay for it after fight, I assumed they would pay for it. So when they were getting the quote, I did not bother to request it to have a look. Now the quote is expensive.

Comment: Ok, so that leaves you the options to just pay it, most likely your least expensive option, or to fight it.  You might discuss this with a local attorney.  Most will give you an initial consultation free of charge.